# onPostExecute ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I write this code for main activity of recycleview with it's adapter and fetching data on it from json data so my question is about the onPostExecute()
I've used before a string so I used .append with it and everything works, now I used an arraylist for the first time so whats the problem with my function

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final ArrayList<MovieItem> NUM_MOVIES = ;
    RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView mMoviesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMoviesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_movies);

        GridLayoutManager LayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        mMoviesList.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);

        mMoviesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NUM_MOVIES);

        mMoviesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadMoviesData();
    }

    private void loadMoviesData() {
        new FetchMoviesTask().execute();
    }

    public class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MovieItem>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<MovieItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String movie = params[0];
            URL moviesRequestUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(movie);

            try {
                String jsonMovieResponse = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(moviesRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<MovieItem> simpleJsonMovieData = OpenMovieJsonUtils.getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(MainActivity.this, jsonMovieResponse);

                return simpleJsonMovieData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MovieItem> movieData) {
            if (movieData != null) {
                for (MovieItem movie : movieData) {
                    mMoviesList.append((movie) + "\n\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.most_popular) {
                loadMoviesData();
                return true;
            }

            if (id == R.id.top_rated) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<MovieItem> mMoviesItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<MovieItem> MoviesItems) {
        mMoviesItems = MoviesItems;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.movie_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.MoviePopularity.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getPopularity()));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(mMoviesItems.get(position).getPhoto()).into(holder.MoviePoster);
        holder.MovieName.setText(mMoviesItems.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMoviesItems.size();
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView MoviePopularity;
        ImageView MoviePoster;
        TextView MovieName;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            MoviePopularity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_popularity);
            MoviePoster = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_movie);
            MovieName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
        }
    }
}
```

also about the `private static final ArrayList<MovieItem> NUM_MOVIES = ;`
when I use int I just used any number but now with arraylist what should I do

Comment: I don't understand... What is your proble?

Comment: my prob is onPostExecute() what should I use instead of append because it give me error

Comment: Post your error and post code of the adapter

Comment: I edit the question and add the adapter code
the error is the here : `mMoviesList.append((movie) + "\n\n\n");`
append in red color and when run app it just crash

Comment: Please show your log.

Comment: Error:(75, 32) error: cannot find symbol method append(String)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're trying to use a method that did not exist for the class.

In your source code, you define mMoviesList as `RecyclerView`:

```
RecyclerView mMoviesList;
```

Then you try the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MovieItem> movieData) {
  if (movieData != null) {
     for (MovieItem movie : movieData) {
         mMoviesList.append((movie) + "\n\n\n");
     }
  }
}
```

There is no `append` method in RecyclerView

Comment: so what should I do can you guide for that

Comment: you should add the movie data to your arraylist